# Python : how many times appears a string in another string

Tags: python

1) Write a function winner that takes three string arguments. The first two arguments represent the sequences of outcomes of coin tosses chosen by the two players of a Penney Ante game. The third argument is the sequence of outcomes that was obtained when effectively tossing a coin repeatedly. The function must return the value 1 if the first chosen sequence (first argument) wins the game, the value 2 if the second chosen sequence (second argument) wins the game, and the value 0 if none of the sequences wins because none of them was observed in the sequence of coin tosses passed as the third argument. In case the first two arguments are the same, an AssertionError must be raised with the message sequences cannot be equal. In case the first two arguments do not have the same length, an AssertionError must be raised with the message sequences must have equal length.

Problem: my codes doesn't work in all cases for example: winnaar('KKK', 'MKK', 'KMKMKKKKMKKKMMMMKMKK')

correct result is: 2
   with my code the result is:  1

```
def winnaar(seq1, seq2, seq3):

    """
    >>> winnaar('KKK', 'MKK', 'KMKMKKKKMKKKMMMMKMKK')
    2
    >>> winnaar('MKM', 'MMK', 'KMKMKKKKMKKKMMMMKMKK')   
    1
    >>> winnaar('MKK', 'KKM', 'KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK')
    0   
    >>> winnaar('MKK', 'MKK', 'KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    AssertionError: reeksen mogen niet gelijk zijn
    >>> winnaar('MKKM', 'MKK', 'KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    AssertionError: reeksen moeten zelfde lengte hebben
    """


    if seq3.find(seq1) > seq3.find(seq2):
        return 1

    if seq3.find(seq1) < seq3.find(seq2):
        return 2

    if seq1 and seq2 not in seq3:
        return 0

    assert (seq1) == (seq2), "ongeldig serienummerreeksen mogen niet gelijk zijn"
    assert len(seq1) != len(seq2), "reeksen moeten zelfde lengte hebben"
```

Comment: Please split this up into two different questions.

Comment: As for the first question - looks like you must flip `>` and `<` operators. Also, this one `seq1 and seq2 not in seq3` is not correct because  it would be evaled like `(seq1) and (seq2 not in seq3)`.

Answer (score 0):

This may help out for problem #1:

```
# [::-1]  --> This means reverse string
seq3 = seq3[::-1] # The reason I reverse strings is because
seq1 = seq1[::-1] # index() gives you the first occurence 
seq2 = seq2[::-1] # the string

if seq1 not in seq3 or seq2 not in seq3:
    return 0
if seq1 > seq2:
    return 1
if seq1 < seq2:
    return 2
```

To anyone else who wants to help, the problems can be found over here: https://dodona.ugent.be/en/exercises/406642900/

Comment: I don't think this might help. It still gives the wrong solution.